# flume1.6 spooldir source ingests only part of file

Tags: java, flume

Thanks for reading this

I am trying to collect logs using flume-1.6.  But I found not all of
   log file is ingested using spooling director source.  Please give
   your suggestions!!

In one test,  I have 369,189 lines in the log file (170M), but I receive only 169,335 lines at the other end. When I check flume.log, it says end of file has been reached and add .COMPLETED to original log file.

I tried with different log file, with about 300,000 lines  and receive 52,410 records at the other end.

Here is the background and configs:

1. The log files are about size of 200M each.
2. flume is configured with spooldir source,  file channel, and kafka sink, as following:

   ```
   #agent definition
   log_agent.sources = spooldirSrc 
   log_agent.channels = fileChannel 
   log_agent.sinks = kafkaSink 

   log_agent.sources.spooldirSrc.channels = fileChannel
   log_agent.sinks.kafkaSink.channel = fileChannel

   # source define
   log_agent.sources.spooldirSrc.type = spooldir
   log_agent.sources.spooldirSrc.spoolDir=/log_path/


   # kafkaSink definition
   log_agent.sinks.kafkaSink.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
   log_agent.sinks.kafkaSink.topic=log-topic
   log_agent.sinks.kafkaSink.brokerList=kafka-host-1:9092,kafka-host-1:9092,kafka-host-1:9092
   log_agent.sinks.kafkaSink.requiredAcks=1
   log_agent.sinks.kafkaSink.batchSize=100

   # fileChannel definition
   log_agent.channels.fileChannel.type=file
   log_agent.channels.fileChannel.checkpointDir=/path/checkpoint/
   log_agent.channels.fileChannel.dataDirs=/path/data
   log_agent.channels.fileChannel.capacity=100000
   ```

I read [flume document](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source),  spooldir source uses Line Deserializer by default.
And I downloaded flume-1.6 sources, and add print lines near end of file-reading to ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader, which is responsible for reading from log.
It seems the reader ends prematurely before reaching EOF.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally,  I found the reason.  LineDeserializer depends on ResettableFileInputStream to read from files. ResettableFileInputStream
has problem reading multi-codepoint unicode characters. The problem is solved in flume1.7.

I replaced flume1.6 ResettableFileInputStream with [source code](https://github.com/apache/flume/tree/trunk/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/serialization) from flume1.7 , recompiled  and replaced flume-ng-core-1.6.0.jar in flume1.6/lib.
Then spooldir source can consume all content of files.

Hope this can help someone who encounters the same bizzar problem.

Please refer to [apache issue site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-2360).